# Automatically navigated to the specific branch of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have already setup Git repository and it contains more than  one branch.

I want to directly open specific branch of  ADF instance.

Is this possible ?  if so, Can  you please let me know the solution.

For example  [https://adf.azure.com/en/home?factory=subscriptions/{{subscription_Id}}/resourceGroups/{{ResourceGroup_Name}}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{{Factory_Name}}/Branch={{Branch_Name}}](https://adf.azure.com/en/home?factory=subscriptions/%7B%7Bsubscription_Id%7D%7D/resourceGroups/%7B%7BResourceGroup_Name%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7B%7BFactory_Name%7D%7D/Branch=%7B%7BBranch_Name%7D%7D)

I tried the below url path it is landing home page  instead of specific branch.
[https://adf.azure.com/en/home?factory=subscriptions/{{subscription_Id}}/resourceGroups/{{ResourceGroup_Name}}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{{Factory_Name}}](https://adf.azure.com/en/home?factory=subscriptions/%7B%7Bsubscription_Id%7D%7D/resourceGroups/%7B%7BResourceGroup_Name%7D%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7B%7BFactory_Name%7D%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can reach to a specific branch directly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I  can reach to a specific branch directly or not.